# Define function that reads from Lists of lists

Tags: python-3.x

Heres a quick example:-

```
setup = [['dog','red','big','ears'],
         ['cat','blue','small','tail']]

def do_it(dummy_parameter):

      if do_it [0][0] == 'dog':
      print 'dog'
      elif do_it [0][0] == 'cat'
      print 'cat'


do_it(setup)
```

Basically looking to go through a list of up to four lists, make an action depending on each of the list contents.. It a bit vague but any assistance would be appreciated! :)

Getting the error

```
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: You should use `if dummy_parameter[0][0] == 'dog'`... Why do you use the function name?

Comment: how do i stop iteration for variable numbers of lists? ie. stop the error:- IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to get all the values from a list and list of list :) 
with recursion :)

```
test = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e'], 'f']


def separate(item):
    try:

        for i in item:
            if type(i) == list:
                separate(i)

            else:
                print(i)
    except IndexError:
        pass


separate(test)
```

Comment: Thanks very much this is very helpful!

Comment: I have a fair chunk of code now.. i am now getting error :-              IndexError: list index out of range - looking for ways around this. The lists will vary in size..

Comment: Try with simple try/except statement look at the code I Have added it